# class error after deployment of laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, deployment

I've got an error after deployment of laravel project: Everything work in local, but I can't install composer on the server, I have added manually the /vendor directory.

I can't dump-autoload or somethings like that.

`FatalThrowableError in 44db61d9559e2ac8d86cb483e8d4d8b9b0f3d796.php line 15: Class 'App\note' not found`

I don't find any info about this.
Thanks

Comment: Try to clear composer dump, then check if class `note` actially is imported in php file. Also try to remove all cache files in directory `/storage/framework/views/`

Comment: hi opv, how to clear composer dump without artisan?

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly also run into issues regarding filenames and the case of your filenames. If your local environment is a Macosx environment running the HFS+ filesystem as an example: `Foo` == `foo` == `FOO`.

So when you reference a file on your local side as `App\Note` but it should actually be `App\note` on a deployed Linux or similar environment you could have issues.

Otherwise as @OPV suggested running `composer dumpautoload` will reset the autoloading. For that artisan does not come into play.

Comment: i can't install composer on my server ( one.com is my hoster) so i don't find any solutiion to dumpautoload.

Comment: As I mentioned, do you have a case-sensitivity issue? Also if you open that file do you see a reference to `App\Note` perhaps and in your controller you use `App\note`.